# Blurry Icons in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide

Is there a trick I can do to Visual Studio 2013 to get the icons to show up crisply?

I'm running my monitor at 1920 x 1080. I'm using the dark theme.

Here's a picture of what the Visual Studio team [indicated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/03/19/improving-high-dpi-support-for-visual-studio-2013.aspx) would be our experience even on a resolution as high as 4k, which mine is not that high. If this was my ux, I would not have posted this question today.

[image]

Here's the same area of my screen. Notice the fuzziness around the edges of the icons.

[image]

But it's really bad over on the property grid. I mean the ones right above  `[+]Font`.

[image]

An IDE can look OK on my monitor, so I don't think it's my monitor. Here's an equivalent area from Android Studio. The little icons to the right of "Component Tree" are crisp enough for my eyes to not notice any degredation.

[image]